# Connecting a 90 Degree PVC Sweep to a Main Panel

Tags: electrical-panel

Can I glue a male threaded fitting to the end of a 90 degree PVC sweep, and use that to route conductors through the side of my main panel? I don't know if I have seen that, usually it's LB conduit bodies.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are these wires going through PVC to their destination? Or are these cables and you are trying to protect them for the last couple of feet? Or something else? A picture of your panel with notations as to what you are trying to do would help.

Comment: 3D Diagram shows main panel with Point A, and Subpanel.  Subpanel is mounted on wall of attached garage.  Yellow line is the route, and can represent 2-2-2-4 cable, or conduit with thhn/thwn-2 wires of appropriate size.  Long green rectangles are my floor joists.  I tried to run 2-2-2-4 ser cable, but couldn't make the bend in the LB, which is shown below the Subpanel.  So now I am looking at conduit for the entire run.  What is an appropriate conduit connection to the side of the main panel at point A?  Can I use a threaded male fitting on a sweep 90, or something other than another LB?

Comment: If you want to use cable, that's fine. **But then don't use conduit**. You may need protection for some sections of the cable, but you don't need to use conduit for that, you can have a large area covered with a piece of plywood, so you have plenty of room to make the turn without the constraints of conduit.

Comment: Agreed.  If I can make the SER cable work, conduit will only be used in the garage from the LB up to the subpanel.